# jquery keydown event is not working properly

Tags: jquery

```
 $("#id").keydown(function(evt) {
     alert('Hello');
 });
```

I tried this, but this is not working, Can you correct this ?

Comment: How about you read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/ `The keydown event is sent to an element when the user first presses a key on the keyboard. It can be attached to any element, but the event is only sent to the element that has the focus.` Can the element selected be focused?

Comment: And did you wrap it in a document ready ?

Comment: no, outside the document ready

Comment: I put it inside the docuement ready and it works properly.thnx @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works: http://jsfiddle.net/rrikesh/v7MdG/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="id">
```

JS:

```
$("#id").keydown(function(evt) {
     alert('Hello');
 });
```

Comment: I didnt wrap it on document ready function. now it work fine. thanx rrikesh

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. I think you must make sure you included jquery. And also make sure your text element has the same Id as used in your jquery code.

In this case make sure the input type is the following.

```
 <input type="text" id="id" />
```

Also press F12 and look in the console what error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `jquery.keydown` in `$(document).ready`. Also make sure that you've unique `id` of the `div`.

HTML:

```
<input  id="yourId" type="text">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#yourId").keydown(function(evt) {
         alert('Hello');
    }); 
});
```